# toLocal8bit send over TCP

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, tcp

Im creating TCP Server/Client application in QT Creator framework. I want to get some data from UI input field and send it over TCP.

Im doing something like this in client application:

```
 void MainWindow::on_btn_login_clicked()
{
    QByteArray text = (ui->login_input->text()).toLocal8Bit();
    char* out = text.data();
    connection->ConnectAndSendData(out);
}
```

and in the ConnectAndSendData function:

```
void TcpConnect::ConnectAndSendData(const char* data)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    int port = 1234;
    socket->connectToHost("localhost", port);

    if(socket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        qDebug() << "connected to s. localhost at port " << port;
        socket->flush();
        socket->write(data, sizeof(data));
        qDebug() << data << "\n";

        socket->waitForReadyRead();
        char* serverresponse;
        socket->read(serverresponse, 128);

        if(serverresponse == MESSAGE_LOGINRQ)
            socket->write(data);
        socket->flush();
        socket->close();
    }
    else
    {
        /**/
    }
}
```

and the data in line socket->write(data, sizeof(data)); is properly send to server, but when server echoes it, it looks like "something/x00/x00/x00/x00" or somethinglike that. Also when i to do something like this:

```
#define MESSAGE_WANTLOGIN "wanlogin"
socket->write(MESSAGE_WANTLOGIN, sizeof(MESSAGE_WANTLOGIN));
```

message is messed up with those null signs.

on the server side receiving data look as simple as:

```
void Thread::readyRead()
{
    socket->flush();
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
    qDebug() << "data received: " << data;
    if(data == MESSAGE_WANTLOGIN)
    {
        socket->write(MESSAGE_LOGINRQ);
    } else
    {
        qDebug() << "error not messageloginrq";
    }
}
```

and like u can assume, though i send "wanlogin" message, server receiving something like "wanlogin/x00/x00" and this if obviously returns false.

this trash is applied on the end of data, and this impossible to check what message was send. The other thing is that maximum size of send data is 8 chars, but also to data of this length trash is applied so it looks like "wanlogin/x00/x00"; however, when i type more chars, for example 10, the send data is just cut to 8 signs, with no /x00s.

So my question is how to clear data from those /x00s and how to send more than 1 byte of information(i need it e.g. to send login and password of user). Sorry if there's some stupid mistake, its my first client/server application which also using multithreading for each client.

Comment: Probably not directly related to your problem but it's a bad idea to use `toLocal8Bit`/`fromLocal8Bit` for data sent to other machines. In a nutshell, "local 8 bit" encoding corresponds to utf-8 on Linux but to utf-16 on Windows. Use `toUtf8`/`fromUtf8` instead.

Comment: unfortunately, for string "wanlogin" it gives "wanlogin/x00", while for "HAHAHAHAHHAHA" gives "HAHAHAHAHHAHA/x00", when for less than 8 chars it gives one /x00 and then /xCD so "asd" will be "asd/x00/xCD/xCD/xCD/xCD"

Comment: @Dmitry I am pretty sure it is not UTF-16 on Windows, as UTF-16 is not a 8-bit encoding. But still your point holds, as using a locally defined encoding for network communication is bad.

Comment: @KarolDrach For the `0xCD`, see my answer. On Windows, allocated memory is initialized with `0xCD`. So what you see is memory that has been allocated, but has never been written to.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(data)` is `4` or `8` depending if you are on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine. It is **not** the size of your data, but the size (in byte) of a pointer.

So what happens is that your actual `wanlogin` is in fact a 6 character string, and you end up sending 2 more bytes. In this case you are lucky: the char array returned by `data()` is null-terminated, so you have one extra `0` that you can access, but accessing the second `0` is undefined behavior i.e anything can happen.

The solution is to use [`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) instead of `sizeof`. Or, better, to directly call `write()` with a `QByteArray` by changing `ConnectAndSendData(const char* data)` to `ConnectAndSendData(const QByteArray &data)`.

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_login_clicked()
{
    const QByteArray text = (ui->login_input->text()).toLocal8Bit();
    connection->ConnectAndSendData(text);
}

void TcpConnect::ConnectAndSendData(const QByteArray & data)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    quint16 port = 1234;
    socket->connectToHost("localhost", port);

    if(socket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        qDebug() << "connected to s. localhost at port " << port;
        socket->write(data);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks u, method with lefting local8bit but removing sizeof() worked. i cant believe solution was so simple :)

Comment: @KarolDrach Still, you should replace `toLocal8Bit()`. It can cause issues if the server and client do not share the same local encoding or if the user input characters that are not supported by the local encoding: `If this string contains any characters that cannot be encoded in the locale, the returned byte array is undefined. Those characters may be suppressed or replaced by another.` If you want to be safe, you'd better use UTF-8.